# Vork PHP framework

Tags: frameworks, mongodb, php

Has anyone used Vork? What has been your experience? 
How does it compare to f3 or lithium? I'm building with MongoDB.
Which one performs better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to lack of popularity and the license which is unsuitable for libraries you won't find many users of this framework. So I'll give you a placeholder answer. The performance comparison is out of scope here, and could not be objective or meaningful anyway.

I have no clue about MongoDB (their website is pretty slow, which indicates no immediate benefit of researching it further). But I've glanced over Vork:

- In comparison to other frameworks it seems a bit disorganized. The naming of include files sans extension is quite unique and actually charming. But the class and directory structure isn't.
- It follows the Pretend-MVC fallacy.
- But my biggest concern is that it encourages oldschool SQL concatenation and escaping (and the naming of said escape function looks dated).
- The templating API looks interesting, but I did not research that much. (**API usability is the crucial part of frameworks, not performance.**)
- Website doesn't appear very inviting, and this impacts the documentation (which isn't quite complete.)
- On the upside, it comes with a lot of utility code. So if you find an intersection of features that you need, then that's a reason to try it out.